# restart sunspot solr when make a deploy with capistrano in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, solr, capistrano

I have a project rails 3.1 in production environment.

**This is my deploy.rb now:**

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load pathe
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p318@global'  
set :rvm_type, :user
set :application, "domain.com"
set :user, 'user'


#set :repository,  "#{user}@ip.ip.ip.ip:~/app"
set :repository, "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/app.git"

set :keep_releases, 3
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "~/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :copy

set :unicorn_conf, "#{deploy_to}/current/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true


role :web, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "ip.ip.ip.ip", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run


namespace :deploy do
  
    task :restart do
        run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -USR2      `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
    end
    task :start do
        run "bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D"
    end
    task :stop do
        run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -QUIT  `    cat #{unicorn_pid}`; fi"
    end
  
end


load 'deploy/assets'

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

I want make these tasks in capistrano. Now I perform these tasks manually:

**1º I kill sunspot solr pid with:**

a) Find the pid with `ps aux | grep 'solr'`

b) Kill pid with `kill pid_number`

**2º Remove index solr in production environment if exist with:**

a) `rm -r solr/data/production/index`

**3º turn on sunspot solr with:**

a) `RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:start`

**4º Reindex models with:**

a) `RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:mongo:reindex`

### My question is:

**How can I add these tasks to my deploy.rb?**

Thank you!

Comment: Usually the way to avoid downtime is to save indexed data elsewhere and call index instead of reindex. Is that what you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a good starting point:

```
namespace :solr do                                                              
  task :reindex do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} sunspot:solr:reindex" 
  end
end
```

You can just call the `rake sunspot:solr:stop` instead of kill? I'm not sure you need to remove the index if you are going to do a reindex...

Comment: The only problem here is that your SOLR is still pointing to the old Capistrano release directory. If you do deploy:cleanup, or manually delete the folder, you'll get: RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error Error: no segments* file found. So hyperrjas's first point is valid - how to kill the process.

Comment: @yuri The Solr data directory should be symlinked from somewhere in side the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
task :stop_solr do
  begin
    run("cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/env rake sunspot:solr:stop RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
  rescue Exception => error
    puts "***Unable to stop Solr with error: #{error}"
    puts "***Solr may have not been started. Continuing anyway.***"
  end
end

#restart and reindex any newly added full search fields:
task :restart_solr do
  begin
    run("cd #{release_path} && /usr/bin/env rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
  rescue Exception => error
    puts "***Unable to start Solr with error: #{error}."
    puts "***Continuing anyway.***"
  end
end

task :reindex_solr do
  begin
    run("cd #{release_path} && /usr/bin/env rake sunspot:reindex RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
  rescue Exception => error
    puts "***Unable to reindex Solr with error: #{error}"
    puts "***Continuing anyway.***"
  end
end
```

Also, as I mentioned in my comment to Kris's answer, you'll have issues if you clean up old Capistrano directories, unless you kill the SOLR process and force it to point to new index files. One way to avoid this scenario is to set up SOLR in a shared directory and reset the symlink during deployment.

Comment: Try symlinking the solr data directory from `"#{shared_path}/solr"` to `"#{release_path}/solr"` in `after deploy:finalize_update`. Then the same Solr data is shared between releases.